# Java creating a shape that consist of asterisks ( spaces dilemma in the for loop within the loop )

Tags: java

Main:

```
public class Main {                                     
  public static void main(String[] args){                                       
    Tree.line(10);                                                                                                                                          
    Tree.line(5);   
    Tree.line(0);                                                                           
  }                                     
}
```

Sub:

```
public class Tree {                                     
  public static void line(int output){                                      
    for(int i=0; i < output; i++){  

      for(int j = 0; j < output - 1; j++)                                       
        System.out.print(" ");  

      for(int k = 0; k < (2 * i + 1); k++)                                      
        System.out.print("*");   

      System.out.println();                                     

      if(output <= 0)                                       
      {                                     
        System.out.println("Error");                                        
      }                                     
    }                                       
  }                                     
}
```

Output:

```
        *
        ***
        *****
        *******
        *********
        ***********
        *************
        ***************
        *****************

    *
    ***
    *****
    *******
    *********

   [BLANK - no error msg]
```

Expected:

```
           *                        
          ***                                       
         *****                                      
        *******                                     
       *********
  *
 ***
*****

Error
```

I wanted to create a triangular shape made with asterisks. My parameter of 10 would round down to closest odd number (9) and if the value 0 was inputted, it would give an error message. I found a similar tutorial online of a Christmas tree, which I implemented it's base, however, my problems are that space seems to have a problem printing out spaces and my error message seems to not print when I declared equals to or less than 0, how would I resolve this problem?

Comment: The number of spaces should be dependent on `i` as well, FYI

Comment: `for(int j = 0; j < output - 1; a++)` - are you sure that is your actual code?

Comment: Also, you may want to check the fact that `output` (what a weird name) is positive *before* executing the rest of the function.

Comment: Oh okay I'll give it a check once again, yeah sorry, I label my variables weird, I use a, b, c so I changed it to i,j,k when posting because you guys use it that way.